# Import Self-Signed SSL Certificates Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, https, jsoup

So I've looked over a few posts concerning the issue of importing SSL certs into the java cacerts file, but after trying to do this both via the command line (in Windows) and portecle, I still cannot get the SSL certificates to work.  I get this error every time I run the program:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException.
```

I am trying to use Jsoup to parse the html file from the site, but I cannot connect due to self signed SSL certs.  Also, I have parsed the file correctly using a local html file, so I know the connection is the issue for sure.  Also, I've tried compiling and running the program both in the command line and with Eclipse IDE.  Any help for correctly importing these certs would be much appreciated!  Also, if there is anyway to ignore SSL certs in java, that would work for me as well.  The portals I'm trying to access are network printers on a secure network, so the extra security from SSL isn't a huge issue.  Thanks!

Comment: please show your network request code